# How to get the content of file properties in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

As the title, my custom properties:

```
#app settings
my.chassisNum=10
```

java code:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:appconf.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my" )
@Component
public class AppConfig {

    private String chassisNum;

    public String getChassisNum() {
        return this.chassisNum;
    }

    public void setChassisNum(String chassisNum) {
        this.chassisNum = chassisNum;
    }
}
```

when Spring Boot start completed, I got the "chassisNum" value is 10.
when I got it in other place when spring-boot not start completed, it get "null"

```
@Component
public class CreateBaseFolder {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CreateBaseFolder.class);
    private File f; 
    @Autowired
    AppConfig appconf;

    public CreateBaseFolder() {

        System.out.println(appconf.getChassisNum());


    }
```

i try many way to get it value,but is false.such as :implements InitializingBean, @DependsOn....

Comment: what do you meant by spring boot not started completely

Comment: How would spring be able to auto wire in a non existing object... You are trying to access auto wired fields inside a constructor... Spring can only inject dependencies into objects that exist which is AFTER the constructor.

Comment: Is there no way to get the property values of the configuration file in the project startup process?That is, there is no way to load the AppConfig after the completion of the loading of the other Bean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assume you has `application.properties` with content:

```
foo.bar=Jerry
```

You will use annotation `@Value`

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GetPropertiesBean {

    private final String foo;

    @Autowired
    public GetPropertiesBean(@Value("${foo.bar}") String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}
```

Of course, we need an entry point

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then run class Application as Spring Boot application, component is autoload, you will see result at console screen

> Jerry

[image]

Comment: Did exactly like that didin't work for me. I am using java 17.  There are two file with me application.properties and application.yml in my project

package xx.xxxtbek.resource.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GetPropertiesBean {
    private final String foo;

    {At}Autowired
    public GetPropertiesBean(@Value("${foo.bar}") String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/74785282/16194563

Answer (score 0):

@Resource
private Environment environment;

environment.getProperty("my.chassisNum");

via this you would be able to access the property of my.chassisNum.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by `@Value` annotation,This annotation can use at the method parameter  as `@Do Nhu Vy` mentioned in his comment. Also you can use it with constructor parameter as well as a class level filed.
e.g:

```
    @Service
    Class TestService {

   @Value("${my.chassisNum}")
   private String chassisNum;

    public void printChassisNum {
    System.out.println(chassisNum)
    }
    }
```

As per it's [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)

> Annotation at the field or method/constructor parameter level that indicates a default value expression for the affected argument.
>
> Typically used for expression-driven dependency injection. Also supported for dynamic resolution of handler method parameters, e.g. in
>   Spring MVC.
>
> A common use case is to assign default field values using "#{systemProperties.myProp}" style expressions.
>
> Note that actual processing of the @Value annotation is performed by a BeanPostProcessor which in turn means that you cannot use @Value
>   within BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor types. Please
>   consult the javadoc for the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class
>   (which, by default, checks for the presence of this annotation).

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a Spring Boot Application, and for me, the problem was that I forgot to add

```
 implements ApplicationRunner
```

to the class and then implement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Myclass.class, args);
}

public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    //the variables are available here
}
```