# @Value in Springboot returns null

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have the application.properties, which is located in the resources

**apllication.properties**

```
hsm.provider=software
hsm.name=TestHsm
hsm.port=3001
hsm.ip=127.0.0.1
hsm.timeout=10000
```

and the **Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hsm")
public class Controller {

  @Value("${hsm.ip}")
  private String ip;

  @Value("${hsm.port}")
  private String port;

  @Value("${hsm.name}")
  private String name;

  @Value("${hsm.timeout}")
  private String timeout;

  @Value("${hsm.provider}")
  private String provider;}
}
```

however when i run application, all variables remain NULL.
What am i missing?

**EDIT**
This is the projectstructure as of the src folder

```
src
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───xyz
│   │           └───hsmservice
│   │               └───hsm
│   │                   └───api
│   │                           Application.java
│   │                           Controller.java
│   │                           HSM.java
│   │
│   └───resources
│       │   application.properties
│       │
│       └───META-INF
│               plugin.xml
│
└───test
    ├───java
    │       LibraryTest.java
    │
    └───resources
```

**EDIT 2**
Here is the application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably your controller class is not picked up by your application scanning. Could you show us your package structure?

Comment: `apllication.properties` are you sure you have not a typo here? should be `application.properties`

Comment: @pleft woops, thats a typo in the question, the one i actually have in the project is correct tho.

Comment: @UroshT. ive added it

Comment: Check out SpringBoot's configuration proeprties to bind external properties to an Object that can be passed. Its cleaner than using @Value everwhere and should by proxy fix your issue. The controller may be being bean'd before the environment has fully refreshed with the properties.

Comment: 1. You are definitely using  the correct @Value annotation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387952/spring-boot-value-is-null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, i solved it with the top answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844551/how-to-get-the-content-of-file-properties-in-spring-boot) Question. I put the variables and @Values in the signature of the constructor and not as class variables.

Comment: I told you this very thing months ago in the comments :)
Glad that you have it running now

Answer (score 16):

Judging by your package structure, those properties should definitely be loaded. Only possible option is that you have instantiated your `Controller` class as `new Controller()` instead of letting spring injecting the class (using `@Autowired` or constructor injection).

Comment: Im actually not sure how i've instantiated it, the only other significant class is application, which starts the whole thing. Ive added the class in the question.

Comment: Just make sure you are not doing `Controller controller = new Controller();`. See more info on how to do it right: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Comment: I didnt. You can see the other class in the new edit, in the question.

Comment: Then where do you use this `Controller` class? How do you know these values are null? Have you debugged it? There isn't any endpoints in your controller either...

Comment: Yea, ive debugged it, i did set a breakpoint in a small constructor under the variables. I orientated myself after [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tutorial by spring.

Comment: It might be a chicken and the egg problem when it comes to class instantiation and application.properties. Try putting your `@Value` annotations to constructor arguments and not fields.

Answer (score 12):

The reason why @Value returns null sometimes is because when you try to use 'application.properties' contents for static variables which is not allowed in spring. Follow this: https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/
and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem. A workaround is to inject the static variable via constructor and it will work. Example: In application.properties: environment.name=${ENVIRONMENT_NAME} In TestClass.java @ Service public class TestClass{ private static String environmentName; @Autowired public TestClass(@Value("${environment.name:development}") String environmentName) { TestClass.environmentName = environmentName; } }

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate class that autowires the values from properties file.
Create a class like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Properties {

    public static String hsmProvider;

    @Autowired
    public Properties(@Value("${hsm.provider}") String hsmProvider){
        Properties.hsmProvider = hsmProvider;
    }

}
```

You can use the property anywhere as `Properties.hsmProvider`

Answer (score 1):

I've added your code into a Spring boot project and it is in a working condition.

Checkout this [53482633](https://github.com/snmaddula-stackoverflow/53482633) repository and follow the instructions to get it up and running.

Also compare your code against this application to figure out what was going wrong at your end.

In case if you still face any issues, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and @Value was not working for controller but working for component classes so i had used below solution.

You can `@Autowire Environment environment` and then `environment.getProperty("hsm.provider")`.

Note: This is just a workaround solution.

Comment: This does not work either unfortunatly, the `environment.getProperty("hsm.provider")`throws me in a InvocationTargetException.

Comment: Could you add to your pom : <build>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>
  </resources>
...

Answer (score 0):

Controller.java

With Lombok

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hsm")
@Data
public class Controller {
    @Value("${hsm.ip}")
    private String ip;

    @Value("${hsm.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${hsm.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${hsm.timeout}")
    private String timeout;

    @Value("${hsm.provider}")
    private String provider;
}
```

Without Lombok ( generated by Intelliji - Refactor DeLombok )

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/hsm")
    public class Controller {
        @Value("${hsm.ip}")
        private String ip;

        @Value("${hsm.port}")
        private String port;

        @Value("${hsm.name}")
        private String name;

        @Value("${hsm.timeout}")
        private String timeout;

        @Value("${hsm.provider}")
        private String provider;

        public Controller() {
        }

        public String getIp() {
            return this.ip;
        }

        public String getPort() {
            return this.port;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getTimeout() {
            return this.timeout;
        }

        public String getProvider() {
            return this.provider;
        }

        public void setIp(String ip) {
            this.ip = ip;
        }

        public void setPort(String port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setTimeout(String timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        public void setProvider(String provider) {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public boolean equals(final Object o) {
            if (o == this) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Controller)) return false;
            final Controller other = (Controller) o;
            if (!other.canEqual((Object) this)) return false;
            final Object this$ip = this.getIp();
            final Object other$ip = other.getIp();
            if (this$ip == null ? other$ip != null : !this$ip.equals(other$ip)) return false;
            final Object this$port = this.getPort();
            final Object other$port = other.getPort();
            if (this$port == null ? other$port != null : !this$port.equals(other$port)) return false;
            final Object this$name = this.getName();
            final Object other$name = other.getName();
            if (this$name == null ? other$name != null : !this$name.equals(other$name)) return false;
            final Object this$timeout = this.getTimeout();
            final Object other$timeout = other.getTimeout();
            if (this$timeout == null ? other$timeout != null : !this$timeout.equals(other$timeout)) return false;
            final Object this$provider = this.getProvider();
            final Object other$provider = other.getProvider();
            if (this$provider == null ? other$provider != null : !this$provider.equals(other$provider)) return false;
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {
            return other instanceof Controller;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            final int PRIME = 59;
            int result = 1;
            final Object $ip = this.getIp();
            result = result * PRIME + ($ip == null ? 43 : $ip.hashCode());
            final Object $port = this.getPort();
            result = result * PRIME + ($port == null ? 43 : $port.hashCode());
            final Object $name = this.getName();
            result = result * PRIME + ($name == null ? 43 : $name.hashCode());
            final Object $timeout = this.getTimeout();
            result = result * PRIME + ($timeout == null ? 43 : $timeout.hashCode());
            final Object $provider = this.getProvider();
            result = result * PRIME + ($provider == null ? 43 : $provider.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Controller(ip=" + this.getIp() + ", port=" + this.getPort() + ", name=" + this.getName() + ", timeout=" + this.getTimeout() + ", provider=" + this.getProvider() + ")";
        }
    }
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    @Autowired
    Controller controller;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
            DemoApplication app = ctx.getBean(DemoApplication.class);
            app.run(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(controller);
    }
}
```

Output:
`Controller(ip=127.0.0.1, port=3001, name=TestHsm, timeout=1000, provider=software)`

Comment: This does not work either, it appears. I get an "Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator'"
I also cant use lombok in this project.

Comment: added code for Controller.java without Lombok, try it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with doing the @Value in my service file.
I was making a new service in my controller file

NOT WORKING:

UserController.java

```
UserService userService = new UserService();
String user = userService.getUser(); // NULL!!
```

UserService.java

```
public class UserService {

    @Value("${hello.world}")
    String hello;

    public String GetUser() {
        return hello;   // NULL!!
    }

}
```

and that was overriding my injection in my UserService file.

So instead, I did the @Value injection in my Controller file, and passed that variable along into my service constructor.

WORKING:

UserController.java

```
@Value("${hello.world}")
String hello;

UserService userService = new UserService(hello);
```

UserService.java

```
public class UserService {

    private String hello;

    // constructor
    public UserService(@Value("${hello.world}") String hello) {
    this.hello = hello;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you annotate your service with @Service ?

Answer (score 0):

@Value returns null because of the following reasons, so make sure

1.The class in which you use **@Value** is not declared as any of the spring initialized class for ex: **component,service,repository**. So make the class as **spring-managed class**

```
@Component
class ClassA {
    @Value("${property.value}")
    private String valueString;
}
```

OR

```
@Service
class ClassA {
        @Value("${property.value}")
        private String valueString;
}
```

OR

```
@Repository
    class ClassA {
        @Value("${property.value}")
        private String valueString;
    }
```

2.You must be passing this class as a newly initialised object, from the place where you are calling the method in this class.  You should **@Autowire** the class in the calling class and then use the method.

```
@Component
public class ClassA {

    private final String propertyValue;

    @Autowired
    public ClassA(@Value("${propery.value}") String propertyValue) {
        this.propertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

See the answer is very simple I have been through the same problem So I am writing this here so that nobody faces it again.

In order to use the values injected in the bean of a class.

***You need to autowire that class in which the injection has been done to another class where you want the values to be used.***

And the injected vales will never be null.

Since once spring has started with autowiring the beans would always be fetched with non null values.

Comment: Needs sample code snippet