# Spring Boot application properties @Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to create a simple Spring Boot Application, creating a GET using resttemplate.getForObject and instead of hard coding the url within the parameter, I want to create a string and leverage @Value to call the url from application.properties.  I've checked videos and the board ([@Value in Springboot returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482633/value-in-springboot-returns-null)) and every time I run my JUnit test the endpoint is null.  I was wondering if someone can take a look at my code and point out what am I doing incorrectly, why is @Value always null and what can I do to fix this?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NhlTeamsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NhlTeamsApplication.class, args);
    }

}

//my controller
public class NhlTeamsController {

    @Autowired
    private NhlTeamsService nhlTeamsService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/requestAllTeams")
    public @ResponseBody String requestAllTeams() {
        return nhlTeamsService.allTeamsService();

    }
}

//my interface
@Component
public interface NhlTeamsService {

    String allTeamsService();
}

//implementation
@Service
@Data
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class NhlTeamsServiceImpl implements NhlTeamsService{

    @Value("${nhl.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;

    @Override
    public String allTeamsService() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate.getForObject(getEndpoint(), String.class);
    }
}

//application.properties
nhl.endpoint=https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams

//JUnitTest
    @Test
    public void nhlAllTeamsTest(){

        NhlTeamsServiceImpl nhlTeamsService = new NhlTeamsServiceImpl();
        System.out.println(nhlTeamsService.allTeamsService());

    }
```

Am I missing any annotations?  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're mixing several distinct concerns. Don't make a single class both an `@Configuration` (a configuration, of course) and an `@Service` (a class that _does something_ in business terms). Additionally, `application.properties` is already pulled in by Boot (no `@PropertySource` required), and `@ConfigurationProperties` is preferable in most cases to `@Value`. Finally, while I suspect you used `@Data` just to get a getter and setter for `endpoint`, don't use it except for actual data; you don't want all the rest of its stuff. Use `@Getter @Setter`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and still get the NPE.  I even created a new Config class using ConfigurationProperties and got the null results.

Answer (score 1):

When you running tests that time you create a new object of NhlTeamsServiceImpl.
But in spring have spring container inside that at run time spring had to initialize that object with all variable & stored.

So when you create a new object it will initialize of spring container & in that it doesn't have to initialize all required thing as @value variable

so do one thing in test case class modified as follows,

```
class junit{
    
    @Autowired
    public NhlTeamsServiceImpl nhlTeamsServiceImpl;

    //JUnitTest
    @Test
    public void nhlAllTeamsTest(){
        //NhlTeamsServiceImpl nhlTeamsService = new NhlTeamsServiceImpl();
        System.out.println(nhlTeamsService.allTeamsService());

    }
}
```

So it will work.

Find below the working snap.
[image]

& same working code add here https://github.com/MaheshMore4321/RunTestCases

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and the variable can't be autowired in Junit, I get no beans found error.  Am I missing an annotation in NhlTeamServiceImpl?

Comment: Got it working.  Had to add NhlTeamServiceImpl as a Bean in NhlTeamsApplication to get the test to work.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hi Eric, Try this solution I had to try at my end it working properly.i had added that code here : https://github.com/MaheshMore4321/RunTestCases

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot the @RestController

Comment: It works, I will compare the differences between my project.  Much appreciated!