# Spring boot instantiate variable from @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have codes as below. I have variable values from application.properties file and how to assign it to another variable? In this case to coreApi variable.

Here is certainly fails because serverKey and clientKey is still null

And I don't want to initiate coreApi inside class action, I want it on variable init level.

Is this possible?

```
@Value(value = "${app.serverKey}")
String serverKey;

@Value(value = "${app.clientKey}")
String clientKey;

private CoreApi coreApi = new ConfigFactory(new Config(serverKey,clientKey)).getCoreApi();
```

Comment: new Config(serverKey,clientKey) causing error. please provide dependent code here

Comment: possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482633/value-in-springboot-returns-null

Comment: new Config(serverKey,clientKey) causing error. Hey you are instantiating "Config" Object using "new" kayword. Then Spring isn't getting involved, and so the annotations will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
 @Autowired
    public void ConfigFactory(@Value("${app.serverKey}") String serverKey,@Value("${app.clientKey}") String clientKey) {
       coreApi = new ConfigFactory(new Config(serverKey,clientKey)).getCoreApi();
    }
```